# Sharing classes between Xamarin.Android and ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.android, code-reuse

I have created a solution with 3 projects in Xamarin Studio: A ASP.Net Server with POCOs, a Shared Library Core and an Android Project but referencing the shared library project on the Android side fails with Incompatible Target Framework.

What can i do to avoid code replication?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the "beta" channel in Xamarin Studio, you'll be able to link the Android project to the PCL.

If you don't want to use the beta version, you can add the PCL files to your Android app. Instead of copy or move, if you select "link" any changes you make to the files will be represented in both the PCL and Android apps.